# Finding asymptotic notation for expected value, variance

Tags: random-variables, asymptotics, expected-value, bernoulli-distribution

$n$ people are choosing numbers $X_1, \ldots , X_n$ randomly (uniformly) and independently, from: $\{1, 2, \ldots , \frac {n}{logn} \} $.

We'll notate $Y$ for the number of triplets $i<j<k$ such that $X_i=X_j=X_k$

We're required to find an asymptotic notation for $E[Y]$ and $Var(Y)$

Regarding the variance, I havent approached that yet.

For the expected value, I've defined a Bernoulli RV $X_i$ such that $X_i=1$ with probablity $P=\frac {logn}{n}$

Yet I'm not sure how to proceed from here, I was thinking of defining a Negative Binomial RV with $r=3$, though I dont know how to move on from that.

Any intuition/direction could help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Let $m$ be the total number of triplets (you should be able to compute $m$, in terms of $n$).

Imagine we enumerate the $m$ triplets, in some predetermined order, from $1$ to $m$. Let $Z_t$ be the relevant indicator variable: $Z_t=1$ if the triplet verifies the condition $X_i=X_j=X_k$

Then $Y = \sum_{t=1}^m Z_t$

Then, to compute $E[Y]$ it's enough to compute $E[Z_t]$. which is easy.

The variance, is a little more complex.

Update: the number for triplets is $m=\binom{n}{3}$ (combinations) . Because the condition $i<j<k$ implies that the elements must be distinct and that, all all possible permutations we restrict to one (equivalently: we dont' take into account the order of the three items).

Now $E[Z_t]=P(X_i=X_j=X_k) = r \frac{1}{r^3}=1/r^2$ where $r=n/\log n$

Hence $$E[Y]= \frac{m}{r^2} = \binom{n}{3}\frac{\log ^2 n}{n^2}=\frac{n (n-1)(n-2)}{6}\frac{\log ^2 n}{n^2} \to \frac{n  \log^2 n}{6}$$

Update 2: As for the variance. We want to compute $E[Y^2]$. But

$$E[Y^2]= \sum_{i=1}^m \sum_{j=1}^m E[Z_i Z_j]$$

where $E[Z_i Z_j]=P(Z_i=1,Z_j=1)$
Now, group those $m^2$ terms, according to how many elements the joined triplets comprise (from three to six). Compute $P(Z_i=1,Z_j=1)$ for each group and sum.

Comment: I'm having a hard time trying to compute $m$, this is a "no reptitions with importance to order of appearance" situation, yet I cant seem to define who I'm working with-

since we need $i<j<k$ I'm thinking about for all $i\in \{1,\ldots,n-2\}$, but I'm not sure how to handle this

Comment: Regarding my last comment-

I've came to the understanding that it's $n \choose{3}$, as $i$ chooses any number, $j,k$ have the probability of $(\frac {n}{logn})^2$ to be the same number.


Does this seem correct?

Comment: After further calculations I've got that $E[Y]=\Theta(\frac {n^5}{log^2n})$ yet this seems very off to me.

Comment: After fixing the probability from $\frac{n^2}{log^2n}$ to $\frac{log^2n}{n^2}$ I've also got that $E[Y]=\Theta(nlog^2n)$ which is great, however, I assumed each triplet's probability to be acceptable is independant from other triplets, therefor it satisfies $Var(Z_{t_1}+Z_{t_2})=Var(Z_{t_1})+Var(Z_{t_1})$, using this, I came to a similar calculation and got that $Var(Y)=\Theta(nlog^2n)$ which is suspiciously similar to $E[Y]$, hence I am unsure of my correctness.

Comment: @Aishgadol the variables $Z_t$ are not independent. I'm not sure you can assume they are approximately or asympotically independent...

Comment: I now understand why they are not independent, yet I'm not sure how to continue with this understanding, got any ideas?

Comment: I've solved according to the updated response, and got that $\Theta (Y)=n^2\cdot log^4n$ , yet I'm unsure of this. Only thing I know I've got going is that I've got that $Var(Y)\geq 0$ which is something.

Comment: $Var(Y)=\Theta (n^2log^4n)$ * , accidentally wrote $\Theta (Y)$